# Swift and objective-c name clash when using core graphics

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6.1

With Xcode 6.1 I'm suddenly getting this error.

```
/...-Bridging-Header.h:5:2: note: in module 'CoreGraphics' imported from /...-Bridging-Header.h:5:
@import CoreGraphics;
 ^
```

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGGeometry.h:271:1: error: definition with same mangled name as another definition
CGPointMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y)`

It only occurs when I call `CGPointMake` from my swift class 
The swift class is using an objective-c class imported in the bridging header that imports core graphics.

I've cleared the module cache and all the derived data and restarted just for good measure. If this isn't an error in the module cache and the core graphics functions are defined in two places i don't know quite how to address it apart from "just don't use that objective-c file" which is what I've done in the mean time to work around it :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `CGPointMake` in Swift:

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 123, y: 456)
```

Comment: Thankyou! sometimes its the simple things that trip you up!